# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'command' was corrupted

Tags: c, stack, runtime

I'm getting this error while running the code above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ln(char *str);
int compare(char *str1, char *str2);
void reverse(char *str, int n);

void main(){

int n;
int len;
char *str;
char command[2];

printf("Enter your string:\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
str = malloc(n);
scanf("%s", str);

printf(">");
scanf("%s", command);

if (compare(command, "ln")) {
    len = ln(str);
    printf("%d\n", len);
}

if (compare(command, "rv")) {
    reverse(str, n);
    printf("The current string is %s\n", str);
}

free(str);
}


int ln(char *str) {
int i = 0;
while (str[i] != '\0') {
    i++;
}

return i;
}

int compare(char *str1, char *str2) {
int i = 0;
while (str1[i] == str2[i] && str1[i] != '\0' && str2[i] != '\0') {
    i++;
}

if (str1[i] == '\0' && str2[i] == '\0') {
    return 1;
}

else {
    return 0;
}
}

void reverse(char *str, int n){
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++){
    char tmp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[n - 1 - i];
    str[n - i - 1] = tmp;
}

}
```

I've searched online, but any related error I've read about was about writing to much to the allocated memory and such things.
The error happens when I enter the values "5 abcde" or "4 abcd" or any other number & string (the number equals the string length), and the "rv" (reverse) command.
While debugging, I found that the code works perfectly, and the error appears only at the last line (after the string has been reversed).

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: _the number equals the string length_ : There is no guarantee that in this code. and `str = malloc(n);` should be `str = malloc(n+1);`

Comment: That's not much better, as the person can still enter 5 and then type 30 characters.

Answer (score 2):

`char command[2];` declares a buffer of length 2. So it can contain a string of length 1 at most because you need one char more for the zero terminator.

As soon as you enter a string longer than 1 during `scanf("%s", command);` you will get a buffer overflow which corrupts the stack, hence the error.

Reserve a longer buffer for example with `char command[200];`

**EDIT**
Other problem:

Instead of `reverse(str, n);` use `reverse(str, ln(str));` . `n` contains the maximum string length used fot `malloc` and the `reverse` function wants the actual string length in the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work. Also, when it was command[2] and i entered the command "ln" it worked well.

Comment: Do you still get the "stack corrupted" problem ? BTW your reverse function doesn't work either.

Comment: Just because it "worked well" doesn't mean it's right.